# Help Parsing a field using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq

The Xml is formatted as follows

```
<ExtraFields>
        <Field id="Attribute 1" description="Attribute1">
          <Value>Value of Attribute 1</Value>
        <Field id="Attribute 2" description="Attribute2">
          <Value>Value of Attribute 2</Value>
        <Field id="Attribute 3" description="Attribute3">
          <Value>Value of Attribute 3</Value>  
</ExtraFields>
```

I am writing a LINQ statement which should return the following values

```
Value of Attribute 1
Value of Attribute 2
Value of Attribute 3
```

it returns me the value of each attribute when the parent node has an attribute of Field id="Attribute X" description="AttributeX"

Comment: Can you post some sample xml? And also ask a question?

Comment: Hi Morpheus, I think a sample of the XML would be helpful and a bit of clarification on exactly what you want.  Your question is a little unclear (at least to me).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I never had to post anything here in the last one year so far. This is my first time. Next time i will stick to the proper standard!! Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var  doc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var results = doc.Descendants("Value").Where(x =>  
x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value.StartsWith("Attribute")).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you posted is malformed XML, assuming your really mean:

```
<ExtraFields>
  <Field id="Attribute 1" description="Attribute1">
    <Value>Value of Attribute 1</Value>
  </Field>
    <Field id="Attribute 2" description="Attribute2">
      <Value>Value of Attribute 2</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field id="Attribute 3" description="Attribute3">
        <Value>Value of Attribute 3</Value>
    </Field>
</ExtraFields>
```

In that case the following solves your problem with LINQ to XML:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var results = doc.Descendants("Value")
                 .Where ( x=> x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value.StartsWith("Attribute")
                              && x.Parent.Attribute("description") != null
                              && x.Parent.Attribute("description").Value.StartsWith("Attribute"))
                 .Select( x => new { Id = x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value, 
                                     Value = x.Value });

foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : Value = {1}", 
                      result.Id, 
                      result.Value));
}
```

Comment: if you checking `x.Parent.Attribute("description") != null` you should also check `x.Parent.Attribute("id")` and all other null checkings.

Comment: that's probably true, I had assumed from the structure of the xml that the id attribute would always be present - if that assumption is wrong by all means, id should have a null check as well